Losing Information while resizing the image in Segmentation task using U-net
I'm using U-net architecture to build a segmentation task of image. During training I have image of size 256256 image. It works very well on the segmentation of same size 256256 or near to size 256*256 (by using torch for resizing). But while I'm using for bigger dimension it seems like model doesn't work at all.
# To resize the image of 1004* 942 
part1_path= '/Users/akshitdhillon/Documents/M.Tech/Project/M.T.P._Colab/full_TEM_image_1.jpg'
part1=cv2.imread(part1_path)

img_tensor = torch.from_numpy(part1).permute(2, 0, 1).float()  
resize_transform = transforms.Resize((256, 256))

img_resized = resize_transform(img_tensor)

logits_mask = model(img_resized.to(DEVICE).unsqueeze(0))
pred_mask = torch.sigmoid(logits_mask)
pred_mask = (pred_mask>0.5)*1.0

test_show(img_resized,pred_mask.detach().cpu().squeeze(0))

I have got very bad segmentation result
For Image size 256*256 Result

For Image size 1004*994 Result

I have tried to crop the bigger dimension image into 8 parts, then the model segment the image accurately but it not what I want what should I do?

In the training data, were the objects all the same size? Were they sized more similar to the top image? A trained UNet will be sensitive to object sizes if it only observes objects of similar scales during training.

Yes, while training all the data are of 256256 size. But Now I want to apply on the size of 1002994 pixel, but while reducing the size from 1002*994, I'm losing the information from image and in the end I got that worst segmentation result

I'm not asking about how big the images are, but rather the size of the objects in the image. The circles at the top appear to be ~25 pixels in diameter, and the circles in the bottom image appear to be ~5 image in diameter. Did the training data contain circles that ere ~5 pixel wide?

While training there are mixed kind of image circles some image are having  ~25 pixels in diameter, also some image contains circle  ~10 pixel in diameter roughly.
